# Media Privacy when URL is available

Tags: php, security

I am working on a website where there are options to set privacy settings for individual images by an user specifying who can view the media.

I update the settings to DB and when someone else apart from whom the user specify visits the page containing media, the PHP script does not allow access. Its fine that way.

Now, say the user has allowed another user "B" to see the image but not user "C" to see the image.

Say the user "B" gets the URL of the image from the user's profile (xyz.com/abc/xyz.jpg) and gives it to "C". Now, since it is a image URL, it is viewable by user "C". There is no PHP script to restrict him in this case.

How do I handle this situation? Can there be any barries put up to avoid this?

(I do know that this is not foolproof since user "B" can anyway download the image and send it to user "C" but still I wanted to know if there is any way to do this)

**PS:** The media can be anything. An image, video, audio, etc.

Comment: You can serve the image using PHP (ie `xyz.com/image.php?name=xyz.jpg`) instead of directly using a static server, that way you control *when* the image is returned case-by-case. Just make sure you set the correct headers.

Comment: @JCOC611: So, wont the user be able to get the image URL from the page that way?

Comment: Only the ones that you allow, because, even if C has the url, the PHP script `image.php` executes every time someone accesses the url, and can *decide* what to respond.

Comment: @vignesh - You can send the user the image as base64 data instead of as a URL. That might not be the best way to do it, though.

Comment: @JCOC611: Thanks. I thought about this already but I thought he would be able to get the image URL since I did not test it. Will do it that way then. This is the only way right?

Comment: @Pikamander2: Hmm. I can but it will be tooooo big. I will take that also into consideration. Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712282/securely-storing-private-images and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171152/creating-a-private-image-folder

Comment: @Pikamander2: That helped. Thanks. Will close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Researched from the links that I posted in my comments)

The easiest way is to use [readFile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

As an example, I uploaded a file named `hello.png` to my own personal server. It's in the root directory, so nobody should be able to access it from the web.

But with this simple PHP script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('/hello.png');
?>
```

Anybody who visits [loltb.com/hello.php](http://loltb.com/hello.php) can see my image.

To add security, you would have to use session data to determine if the user is allowed to see the image or not. After doing that, the code will look something like:

```
if ($userAllowedToSeeImage)
{
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    readfile('/hello.png');
}

else
{
    echo("go away");
}
```

I've seen websites like Dropbox do this before, but I wasn't entirely sure how to implement it until I Googled your question. Thanks for helping me learn something!